# Free online UML tool

Tags: uml, browser-based

I am looking for free online (flash, silverlight, or javascript - simply "browser-based") tool for creating UML diagrams & ER diagrams. In the past, there was great tools like cacoo.com, creately.com, gliffy.com, or lucidchart.com. But now, they are all paid or limited for free users.

So, is there any **free online** tools, which can do that?

Thank you for your tips.

Answer (score 4):

GenMyModel seems to match: [UML tool](http://www.genmymodel.com). It is an online modeler in the cloud. It does more than drawing as you get models conforming the UML metamodel. It's free and online. Presently for class diagrams and use case diagrams.

Comment: Indeed, it is free, but it is limited to one UML project.

Answer (score 0):

EverGraph is free for use and despite being notation agnostic can handle program structure / architecture visualization: http://evergraph.io

Comment: I'm use this [gwtuml](http://gwtuml.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/GWTUMLDrawer/war/GWTUMLDrawer.html#Start) good for drafts